# SQL datetime conversion

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have the following code...

```
SELECT

CAST (pos.DateShipped AS DATE) AS DateShipped,
COALESCE(s.Code, c1.CountryName) AS Region_Name,
c2.CurrencyCode,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
SUM(pos.PriceIncTax / (1 + ct.TaxRate) * ct.TaxRate * pos.Quantity * pos.ExchangeRate) AS VAT_Sales_Curr

FROM
dbo.POSItem (NOLOCK) pos
JOIN dbo.ReceiptDrop (NOLOCK) RD ON rd.ReceiptId = pos.ReceiptId
LEFT JOIN dbo.CountryTax (NOLOCK) CT ON rd.CountryId = ct.CountryId AND pos.DateShipped >= ct.DateFrom AND (pos.DateShipped < ct.DateTo OR ct.DateTo IS NULL)
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.State (NOLOCK) S ON rd.CountryId = s.CountryId AND rd.County = s.Code
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Country (NOLOCK) C1 ON rd.CountryId = c1.CountryId
LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Country (NOLOCK) C2 ON pos.CurrencyId = c2.CountryId

WHERE
pos.DateShipped >= '28-07-2014'
AND pos.DateShipped < '02-09-2014'
AND pos.DateShipped IS NOT NULL
```

and it is generating the error ....

> The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.

can you advise on the simplest way to correct this in SQL 2008

Many thanks,

Comment: (NOLOCK) should be given as WITH (NOLOCK)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For converting varchar to datetime use this

convert(datetime,column_name,101)

101 for data format mm-dd-yyyy
103 for dd-mm-yyyy

for Example convert(datatime,pos.DateShipped,103) >= '28-07-2014'